# Getting OOM for postgresql when working with spark

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-spark

I have several transformation steps.

1. I unload data from the database.
2. I do four conversion steps, but on the fourth my database dies with OOM. Amount of data uploaded from postgresql database ~ 3g.
3. I want to upload the data back to the database, but on such an amount of data it does not reach this step.

pg_stat_activity shows active requests before OOM

| query | duration |
| --- | --- |
| SELECT "parent_id","root_id" FROM (select * from "temp_2166008c_4a87_4f77_a267_077adde08453_v2") SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_16 WHERE ("parent_id" IS NOT NULL) | 00:06:13.401819 |
| SELECT "object_id","parent_id","attr_id" FROM (select * from "temp_2166008c_4a87_4f77_a267_077adde08453_v2") SPARK_GEN_SUBQ_16 WHERE ("object_id" IS NOT NULL) | 00:06:13.401819 |

the code on which the OOM is supposed to occur

```
Dataset<Row> iter4 = iter_3
            .groupBy(
                    col("super_parent"),
                    col("parent_id").cast("string").as("parent_id")
            )
            .pivot("attr_id")
            .agg(first(col("value")).cast("string").as("value"))
            .as("iter_4");
```

Spark: I use one master node and two worker nodes with 3g of RAM each.

```
    2023-04-13 08:57:18.556  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [ckManagerMaster] o.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerInfo  : Added broadcast_14_piece0 in memory on 172.20.0.4:9260 (size: 7.2 KiB, free: 434.2 MiB)
2023-04-13 08:57:31.141  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Finished task 0.0 in stage 38.0 (TID 18) in 12679 ms on 172.20.0.4 (executor 0) (1/1)
2023-04-13 08:57:31.141  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Removed TaskSet 38.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2023-04-13 08:57:31.144  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : ShuffleMapStage 38 (pivot at DetailMerge.java:71) finished in 12.705 s
2023-04-13 08:57:31.145  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : looking for newly runnable stages
2023-04-13 08:57:31.145  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : running: Set(ShuffleMapStage 39, ShuffleMapStage 40)
2023-04-13 08:57:31.145  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : waiting: Set()
2023-04-13 08:57:31.145  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : failed: Set()
2023-04-13 09:02:49.883  WARN [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-3] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.0 in stage 39.0 (TID 19) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2603)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.next(PgResultSet.java:2235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:168)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receive(PGStream.java:660)
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveTupleV3(PGStream.java:618)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2368)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2598)
        ... 21 more

2023-04-13 09:02:49.889  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.1 in stage 39.0 (TID 21) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:49.889  WARN [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-0] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 20) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: An I/O error occurred while sending to the backend.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2603)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet.next(PgResultSet.java:2235)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anon$1.getNext(JdbcUtils.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:760)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:168)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:467)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.fetch(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2598)
        ... 21 more

2023-04-13 09:02:49.890  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.1 in stage 40.0 (TID 22) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:50.138  WARN [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-1] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.1 in stage 40.0 (TID 22) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2023-04-13 09:02:50.139  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.2 in stage 40.0 (TID 23) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:50.141  WARN [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.1 in stage 39.0 (TID 21) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2023-04-13 09:02:50.143  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.2 in stage 39.0 (TID 24) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:50.180  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-3] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.2 in stage 40.0 (TID 23) on 172.20.0.4, executor 0: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode) [duplicate 1]
2023-04-13 09:02:50.184  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.3 in stage 40.0 (TID 25) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:50.186  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-0] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.2 in stage 39.0 (TID 24) on 172.20.0.4, executor 0: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode) [duplicate 1]
2023-04-13 09:02:50.190  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [rainedScheduler] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Starting task 0.3 in stage 39.0 (TID 26) (172.20.0.4, executor 0, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4292 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
2023-04-13 09:02:50.211  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-1] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.3 in stage 39.0 (TID 26) on 172.20.0.4, executor 0: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode) [duplicate 2]
2023-04-13 09:02:50.213 ERROR [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-1] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Task 0 in stage 39.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
2023-04-13 09:02:50.217  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-1] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Removed TaskSet 39.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2023-04-13 09:02:50.218  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Lost task 0.3 in stage 40.0 (TID 25) on 172.20.0.4, executor 0: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException (FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode) [duplicate 2]
2023-04-13 09:02:50.218 ERROR [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  : Task 0 in stage 40.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
2023-04-13 09:02:50.219  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [result-getter-2] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Removed TaskSet 40.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
2023-04-13 09:02:50.220  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Cancelling stage 39
2023-04-13 09:02:50.220  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Killing all running tasks in stage 39: Stage cancelled
2023-04-13 09:02:50.222  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : ShuffleMapStage 39 (pivot at DetailMerge.java:71) failed in 331.754 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 39.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 39.0 (TID 26) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
2023-04-13 09:02:50.226  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Cancelling stage 40
2023-04-13 09:02:50.226  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] o.a.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl    : Killing all running tasks in stage 40: Stage cancelled
2023-04-13 09:02:50.227  INFO [mig-tool,,,] 19916 --- [uler-event-loop] org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler  : ShuffleMapStage 40 (pivot at DetailMerge.java:71) failed in 331.723 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 40.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 40.0 (TID 25) (172.20.0.4 executor 0): org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:693)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.BasicConnectionProvider.getConnection(BasicConnectionProvider.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.connection.ConnectionProviderBase.create(ConnectionProvider.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1(JdbcDialects.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialect.$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1$adapted(JdbcDialects.scala:118)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Who is going OOM, java or postgresql or spark, and how do you know?  You said "the database", but I'm not confident that you have assessed that correctly.

Comment: Did you check the log files? Anything interesting?